# Maximum call stack size exceeded array inside arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was try to modify an array to include others array inside him and I got the **Maximum call stack size exceeded** and have no idea why.

```
app.selected.forEach(function(customer) {
        app.dateInterval.forEach(function(dateint) {
            customer[+dateint] = []

            app.eventsEmail.forEach(function(event) {
                var date = event.Data;
                date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
                date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

                if (event.IdCustomer == customer.IdCustomer && (+date) == (+dataint))
                    customer[+dateint].push(event);


            }); 
        }); 
    });
```

Someone have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: have you debuged your code in devTools in browsers?

Comment: What is purpose of two nested `.forEach()` calls within a `.forEach()` call?

Comment: There is no reason why this should overflow the call stack. Can you add the code from where all this is called? Any recursive calls?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
var size = app.selected.length;
for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        var customer = app.selected[i];
        app.dateInterval.forEach(function(dateint) {
            customer[+dateint] = []

            app.eventsEmail.forEach(function(event) {
                var date = event.Data;
                date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 0, 0, 0);
                date = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

                if (event.IdCustomer == customer.IdCustomer && (+date) == (+dataint))
                    customer[+dateint].push(event);


            }); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: How does this fix the problem? What **was** the problem?

Comment: the problem is you are adding item and length increases and have foreach on that ... infinite loop